# TinyMCE Templates Plugin window is too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I'm having a problem with the TinyMCE Template selection window.

Templates is a TinyMCE plugin that (I think) uses jqueryUI to open a popup window which allows the author to select from a collection of ready-built html templates.

This is all working fine. The problem I'm having is that the popup window is too big

I've created a TinyMCE fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/zpeaab

[image: TinyMCE template button]

If you click the Template button (see image) the popup opens, but then it's not possible to click the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button because it's off the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to

- resize the window?
- make the window resizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some additional settings:

```
template_popup_height : 300
template_popup_width  : 500
```

This allows me to set the jQueryUI window properties. Seems to only accept integer numbers (e.g. neither '60%' or '300px' seemed to work)

This has allowed me to at least make the window small enough to fit on the screen